# JMS ActiveMQ and Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, jms

I'm here for asking some information about JMS.
I m using a Netbeans and ActiveMQ for make a simple topic and subscribe

In lab class we developed just a consumer (because professor had already create a server) but at my house i need produce and consumer to make something.

i m starting from this example https://javainsider.wordpress.com/tag/jms-with-activemq-sample-example/

i create in Netbeans a Java Web Application for the Producer and lunch it.
and after i create Java Application for the consumer. 
we i lunch (server and client ) i receive just this message

" INFO | Successfully connected to tcp://localhost:61616"

So i understand that i wrong something in the creation of the project. 
If i see in the localost of ActiveMQ , in queques i don't have nothing.

Anyone can help me with this stuff.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which framework are you using?

If you are using spring frame work you need to eastablish connection in your application context file.

You can use below code for reference. (I have used queue instead of topic)

for setting up a producer:

```
 <bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
        <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="ExportQueue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
        <constructor-arg value="ExportQueue"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
        <property name="receiveTimeout" value="10000"/>
    </bean>  
    <bean id="JMSExportProducer" class="com.krawler.spring.accounting.jms.JMSExportProducer">
        <property name="jmsTemplate" ref="jmsTemplate"/>
    </bean>
```

For Consumer:

```
<bean id="JMSExportConsumer" class="com.krawler.spring.accounting.reports.JMSExportConsumer">
        <property name="destination" ref="ExportQueue"/>
        <property name="jmsTemplate" ref="jmsTemplate"/>
 </bean>

    <bean id="jmsExportContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="concurrentConsumers">
            <value>25</value>
        </property>
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
        <property name="destination" ref="ExportQueue"/>
        <property name="messageListener" ref="JMSExportConsumer"/>
    </bean>
```